# Error C2679 when using '+' operator in a template to add template class and parameter class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to create a template class representing a set of elements that overloads '+' operator in two ways:
like this: `someNewSet = setA + setB;`
and this: `someNewSet = setA + newElement;`

(I'm aware that's a bad practice to use it like that, but please bear with me.)

However, I keep running into a problem with the latter that can be shown by this example:

foo.h:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    T bar;
public:
Foo(T arg);
    template<typename TT> friend Foo<TT> operator + (Foo<TT>& a, Foo<TT>& b);
template<typename TT> friend Foo<TT> operator + (Foo<TT>& a, TT& element);
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(T arg) {
    bar = arg;
}

template<typename T>
Foo<T> operator + (Foo<T>& a, Foo<T>& b) {
        return Foo<T>(b.bar);
}

template<typename T>
Foo<T> operator + (Foo<T>& a, T& element) {
    return Foo<T>(element);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    Foo<int> f(5);
    Foo<int> g(3);

    f + g;//works fine

    f + 5;//generates error

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
};
```

error message:

> error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-    hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  [file path]/main.cpp [project name here]

Also, build output window in Visual Studio 2013 shows:

> main.cpp
>   [file-path]\main.cpp(43): error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> ```
>      [file path]\foo.h(27): could be 'Foo<int> operator +<int>(Foo<int> &,T &)'
>      with
>      [
>          T=int
>      ]
>      while trying to match the argument list '(Foo<int>, int)'
> ```

Trying to use, say, function `template<typename TT> friend Foo<TT> add (Foo<TT>& a, TT& element);` produces similar results.

I also tried forward declaring both template class and the problematic function (and adding `<>` before the argument list), but that didn't help.

I'm not missing something obvious here, am I?

Comment: Can you try with `const` reference parameters instead of non-const? There is no reason why `operator+` should change its arguments.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. It actually seems to have solved the problem. I need to just test the actual code a bit to see if I'm not jumping at a conclusion.

Comment: OK, I added an answer with a very simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be boiled down to this:

```
struct Foo {};

Foo operator+(Foo&, int&) { return Foo(); }

int main()
{
  Foo f1;
  Foo f2 = f1 + 42;
}
```

Your parameters are non-const references, and you are passing arguments that cannot be bound to these (42 in my example, 5 in yours). You can fix this changing the operator parameters to `const` references. This makes sense anyway, because a binary operator shouldn't really change its operands. The example above can be fixed like this:

```
Foo operator+(const Foo&, const int&) { return Foo(); }
```

Comment: Yes, that was that problems. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dragomok Glad it helped. In the future, you may try to boil the problem down to something minimal like the example in my answer. It will help you understand the problem better, you might even solve it yourself, or if not, it will make it easier for others to solve.